# remove clicked button div on button click

Tags: php, javascript

i m getting data from databse, number of div depend on the number of records but i m getting wanted result if i click 4th button the first div is removed but i want it to remove 4th div not first, my code is here

```
<button class="mws-button red" type="button" id="red_remove_<?php echo $i;?>"onclick="rem(id,id);">Remove</button>
```

i have called this function on button click

```
var count=0;
function rem(key,l){
$('#remove_more_opertaion'+count).remove();
$('#label'+count).remove();
count++;
}
```

Comment: Start `count` at  `$("[id^=remove_move_operation]").length` and use `count--` instead

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner way to do it using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<button class="mws-button red remove-btn" 
        type="button"
        data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"  // <-- will use this id to remove corresponding div
        id="red_remove_<?php echo $i;?>">Remove</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.remove-btn').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#remove_more_opertaion' + id).remove();
    $('#label' + id).remove();
});
```

Alos no need to use `onclick="..."` since you have jQuery.

Comment: nice use of the data attributes

Answer (score 0):

use the split function and match the number and deleted clicked button div